# I guess I don't "get" async programming

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I've been using node.js for about 6 months now, off and on.  But, I guess I still don't completely understand designing a program around asynchronous calls.

Take, for example, my most recent program, that needs to read a config, use that config to connect to the database, and then connect to every address in the database asynchronously.

I'm using the modules [fnoc](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fnoc) and [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql), but this is just pseudocode.

```
// first, get the config
fnoc(function(err, confs){
   // code stuff in here

   //now check that there's a database config
   if (confs.hasOwnProperty("database"))
   {
      // set up db connection
      var mysql_conn = mysql.createConnection({
          host:   confs.database.host,
          user:   confs.database.user,
          password:       confs.database.password,
          database:       confs.database.database
      });
      // do some querying here.
      mysql_conn.query(query, function(err, records, fields){
          records.forEach(function(host){
              // four levels in, and just now starting the device connections
          });
      });


   }
});
```

Every time I write something like this with callback inside of callback inside of callback, I feel like I'm doing something wrong.  I know of promises and the async node library, but it seems like if those are the solutions, they should be default functionality.  Am I doing something wrong, or is it just not clicking for me?

EDIT:  Some suggestions include using functions for the callbacks, but that seems worse somehow (unless I'm doing it wrong, which is entirely possible).  You end up calling one function inside of another, and it seems especially spaghetti-ish.

The example above, with functions:

```
function make_connection (hosts) {
hosts.foreach(function(host){
      //here's where the fun starts
    };
}


function query_db(dbinfo){
    var mysql_conn = mysql.createConnection({
          host:  dbinfo.host,
          user:  dbinfo.user,
          password:       dbinfo.password,
          database:       dbinfo.database
    });

// do some querying here.
    mysql_conn.query(query, function(err, records, fields){
    make_connection(records);
});

}



// first, get the config
fnoc(function(err, confs){
   // code stuff in here

   //now check that there's a database config
   if (confs.hasOwnProperty("database"))
   {
      // set up db connection

      query_db(confs.database);
      var mysql_conn = mysql.createConnection({
          host:   confs.database.host,
          user:   confs.database.user,
          password:       confs.database.password,
          database:       confs.database.database
      });
      // do some querying here.
      mysql_conn.query(query, function(err, records, fields){
          records.forEach(function(host){
              // four levels in, and just now starting the device connections
          });
      });


   }
});
```

Comment: Continuation passing style (that applies to this, right?) does take some getting used to.

Comment: If you properly split it into functions rather than trying to force everything into one big piece of code, the "callback hell" becomes managable. Spaghetti code is always a bad pattern, callbacks or not.

Comment: It looks fine to me. You could separate the output and the input of the callback, which makes it more manageable (and more important) composable. For example functional reactive programming is such a solution: [bacon](http://sean.voisen.org/blog/2013/09/intro-to-functional-reactive-programming/). Then you are essentially building circuits, where the data flows through.

But to be hones, you need to wrap your brain around it too, because it is a whole paradigm, not just a library.

Answer (score 1):

The aim of asynchronous functions and callbacks is to avoid any conflicts (which can happen more than you think!) between objects.

I'd like to point you to this asynch enthusiast: http://www.sebastianseilund.com/nodejs-async-in-practice

Yes, the callbacks do take some getting use to, but it's worth it!

Comment: That blog link is exceptional, especially since I'm doing some of each of what he is talking about.  I will be using this.

Answer (score 0):

In short words: instead of

```
foo(function () {
    // ... stuff #1 ...

    bar(function () {
        // ... stuff #2 ...

        baz();
    });
});
```

do

```
foo(handleFoo);

function handleFoo() {
    // ... stuff #1 ...

    bar(handleBar);
}

function handleBar() {
    // ... stuff #2 ...

    baz();
}
```

Of course, it can (and maybe should) be more granular, but that depends on the actual code. This is just a pattern to avoid nesting functions. You can also encapulsate these methods more.

This is the "vanilla" approach. There are also libraries that allow you managing this in nice ways.

Comment: I considered this, but wouldn't I just end up calling one function inside of another (like calling the database querying function inside the config read function?)?  It seems like even worse code somehow.

Comment: It's not spagetti-ish if done right (e.g. in a "step-by-step pattern" with encapsulation of the steps). Yes, function calls are still nested, but there is absolutely nothing wrong with that. Any libraries you can use will still do the same, just maybe "behind the scenes". I would only agree that with such libraries mit might be a) more comfortable and b) look&feel cleaner even if it is technically the same. Anyway, proper separation is definitely not an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel really tired of endless callbacks, try [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) or [co](https://github.com/visionmedia/co). You can write node.js code like this:

```
co(function *(){
  var a = get('http://google.com');
  var b = get('http://yahoo.com');
  var c = get('http://cloudup.com');
  var res = yield [a, b, c];
  console.log(res);
})()
```

It's almost a different way of writing, so it can be difficult to grasp but the results are quite good.

Comment: Yah, I did some promises with Q a couple of months ago.  It's cool, but I feel like I should learn how things are "supposed" to work before I start using shortcuts.

Comment: @coding_hero promises are **not** shortcuts for callbacks and work compeletely differently. In fact to get most benefit from promises you need to forget everything about callbacks because any callback thinking when using promises will result in absolutely hideous code (which is probably leading cause on why most people don't see advantage in promises lol). Callbacks are simply inferior and any learning of them is waste of time and even harmful - almost every other language uses promises for async and not callbacks.